# Multiple plots against Date and Time using MatPlotLib and Sql3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, sqlite

This may have been asked before but I have been unable to find it.

I am a newbie to programming and working on a project to actively monitor and record voltage levels of four devices.  These details are stored in a sqlite3 db with the date and time they were taken.

I am now trying to create a plot in Matplotlib with all four traces on the same graph, by using the Sqllite3 data.  I have got one working although it is a little messy.

Here is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from dateutil import parser
import time
import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect ('Test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def graph_data():
        c.execute('SELECT DTG, Battery_Level1, Battery_Level2, Battery_Leve3, Battery_Level4 FROM Voltages')
        data = c.fetchall()
        dates = []
        values = []

        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Voltage')
        plt.title('PiPower Manager')

        for row in data:
            dates.append(parser.parse(row[0]))
            values.append(row[1])

        plt.plot_date(dates, values,'-',)



        plt.show()

graph_data()
c.close
conn.close()
```

However I try to add the other lines it appears to cause an error.  Any help would be appreciated.

---

Update 1

I have mostly tried playing with the section

```
for row in data:
    dates.append(parser.parse(row[0]))
    values.append(row[1])
```

I have added a new section similar as below

```
for row in data:
    dates.append(parser.parse(row[0]))
    values.append(row[2])
```

This does graph but looks odd - If I hash out the original it plots ok.

I have then tried adding row[3] and row [4] but I get an error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/plot.py", line 41, in <module>
    graph_data()
  File "/home/pi/plot.py", line 28, in graph_data
    values.append(row[3])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I am not really sure how to go about this......

Comment: What is your code to add the other lines, and what is the error message?

Comment: whrrgarbl please see my updated edit on the main post.

Comment: I would also like a legend!!!!! and varying colours